# Can't test a remote HTML/CSS/JS/Java website with Cucumber + Selenium Webdriver + Chrome + Capybara

Tags: java, selenium, applet, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to test with Cucumber + Selenium + Capybara a remote HTML/CSS/JS website which uses a Java .
The website works fine on the Chrome browser, but when I launch my test, the Chrome browser is launched on the website, but the Java applet is not loaded at all.

Looks like the Chrome browser environment launched by Webdriver does not load any third party chrome plugins like Java.

Is there any way to circumvent this ?

Thanks in advance, best regards

Geoffroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a custom profile with the following code:

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--user-data-dir=/path/to/profile/directory"));
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

See the selenium chrome documentation: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It was very helpful. Now I'm blocked somewhere else but at least I made some progresses.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe try [Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) instead of Webdriver. I haven't personally tried Selenium RC with third party tools, but it could an option to try while you're looking for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Danish. The problem is Selenium Remote Control is officially deprecated. But I can still try and see if I can make it work with Cucumber and Capybara. Cheers

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is deprecated. How about trying WebDriver with other browsers e.g. IE or Firefox. This may give you some clue to whether its a limitation of WebDriver or the Chrome implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately the website I'm trying to test is Chrome only... it's a very specific website.